# Does python automatically decode ASCII and UTF-8 byte strings?

Tags: python, byte

From what I understand, a Python3 string is a sequence of bytes that has been decoded to be readable by humans, and a Python3 bytes object are the raw bytes that are not human readable. What I'm having trouble understanding, however, is how strings encoded with UTF-8 or ASCII are displayed as a string prefixed by a b, rather than a sequence of bytes

```py
string = "I am a string"

# prints a sequence of bytes, like I would expect
string.encode("UTF-16")
b'\xff\xfeI\x00 \x00a\x00m\x00 \x00a\x00 \x00s\x00t\x00r\x00i\x00n\x00g\x00'


# Prints a sequence of human readable characters, which I don't understand
string.encode("UTF-8")
b'I am a string'
```

Why does a string encoded by UTF-8 or ASCII not display a sequence of bytes?

Comment: "Why does a string encoded by UTF-8 or ASCII not **display** a sequence of bytes?" - The hint is in the question. What is being "displayed" *HAS* to be a design choice, and well, would you rather look at byte strings as numbers or bytestrings that we can understand. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTF-8 is a backwards-compatible superset of ASCII, i.e. anything that’s valid ASCII is valid UTF-8 and everything present in ASCII is encoded by UTF-8 using the same byte as ASCII. So it’s not “UTF-8 or ASCII” so much as “just some of ASCII”. Try other Unicode:

```
>>> "café".encode("UTF-8")
b'caf\xc3\xa9'
```

or other ASCII that wouldn’t be very helpful to look at in character form:

```
>>> "hello\f\n\t\r\v\0\N{SOH}\N{DEL}".encode("UTF-8")
b'hello\x0c\n\t\r\x0b\x00\x01\x7f'
```

The reason the `repr` of `bytes` displays printable characters instead of `\xnn` escapes when possible is because it’s helpful if you do happen to have bytes that contain ASCII.

And, of course, it’s still a well-formed `bytes` literal:

```
>>> b'I am a string'[0]
73
```

Additionally: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes)

> While bytes literals and **representations are based on ASCII text**,
>   bytes objects actually behave like immutable sequences of integers,
>   with each value in the sequence restricted such that 0 <= x < 256
>   (attempts to violate this restriction will trigger ValueError). This
>   is done deliberately to emphasise that while many binary formats
>   include ASCII based elements and can be usefully manipulated with some
>   text-oriented algorithms, this is not generally the case for arbitrary
>   binary data

-emphasis added.

At the end of the day, this is a design choice that python made for displaying bytes.